# How to Disable dynamic searching when typing in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want to disable default search when typing in the listbox.
For example I type `L` and the `M` into the listbox, the focus should move to string starting with `LM`, but here focus moves to string starting with `M`.
This is because the default behaviour algorithm/code that I have written gets overwritten and the focus moves to string starting with `M`.

Comment: You'll need to supply way more context.

Comment: I want to disable default search when typing in the listbox

Say i type L
Then  i type M into the listbox
Then focus should move to string starting with LM 
But here focus moves to string starting with M
This is because of this default behaviour 
algorithm/code that i have written get override
and the focus moves to string starting with M
Can you please help me?

Comment: Please Help me
I could not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to [implement auto-complete on the combo box](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/autocomplete_combobox.aspx). The easiest way to do this is inherit from the system combo, and handle the `KeyUp` event to implement the functionality.

Comment: this is not what i want 
I want to disable dynamic searching in listbox not in combo box 

and i already exactly earlier what i want

Comment: That's how I interpreted your description "Say i type L Then i type M into the listbox Then focus should move to string starting with LM " - perhaps you could clarify further?

Comment: yes I want exactly  what you are saying if I type L and then M  in Listbox then focus should move to string starting with LM 
so that user can selected that particular item  form the listbox 

I have written the code on listbox keydown event but default behaviour of listbox override my code and focus moves to string starting with say M(second letter that is typed )  in the listbox

Please Help Me?